# Javascript chai why throw not caught?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing a Nodejs server using `mocha` and `chai` on Windows 10.
One function to access a database throws if the key is not existent. Why putting it under `expect` like this:

```
expect(db.getReferenceData("not-existent")).to.throw();
```

fails? Instead, putting it inside another function works:

```
expect(function() {
    db.getReferenceData("not-existent");
}).to.throw();
```

The examples in the documentation seem to imply the first call is correct, at least for me.

Thanks for your help!
mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example the exception is thrown before `expect()` is called. You need to postpone the execution of `db.getReferenceData`, to allow `expect` to catch the exception.